# Ubuntu linker not resolving symbols when linking a shared library

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, linker

I am playing with some basic Python bindings for libturbojpeg I would like to use in a project of mine. Everything works perfectly in Debian (sid), but when building the project with Ubuntu (trusty) the linker is apparently unable to resolve symbols correctly.

The codebase is here in https://github.com/subotto/streaming. `make _pytj.so` should do the trick and it works on Debian (it uses SWIG to generate C code, compiles it with other custom code of mine and then links it). The generated library `_pytj.so` has all the correct dependencies.

Instead on Ubuntu the generated libraries misses dependencies:

```
$ ldd _pytj.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff968e2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12229d8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1222fe0000)
```

(it should depend on turbojpeg and Python libraries too).

Of course, if I try to import the generated module, python interpreter complains about unresolved symbols.

If I add `-Wl,-z,defs` to the linking compilation line:

```
$ gcc -shared -o _pytj.so `python-config --libs` -lturbojpeg _pytj.o  _pytj_wrap.o -Wl,-z,defs 2>&1 | head
_pytj.o: In function `create_tjcontext':
_pytj.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `tjInitCompress'
_pytj.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `tjInitDecompress'
_pytj.o: In function `free_tjcontext':
_pytj.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `tjDestroy'
_pytj.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `tjDestroy'
_pytj.o: In function `encode_image':
_pytj.c:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `tjCompress2'
_pytj.o: In function `free_encoded_image':
_pytj.c:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `tjFree'
```

Clearly, the linker understanding my request to link to the specified libraries. As I said, the same command line in Debian sid works perfectly.

What am I missing?

**EDIT** If I use the another command line, as suggested in a comment, I have another error:

```
$ gcc -shared -o _pytj.so _pytj.o _pytj_wrap.o `python-config --libs` -lturbojpeg -Wl,-z,defs 2>&1 | head
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.a(libturbojpeg_la-turbojpeg.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is however my understanding that libraries with `-l` have to be indicated before the objects that use them.

Comment: The linker is sometimes a pain to get "just right". Try putting the libraries after the objects to link (i.e. run `gcc -shared -o _pytj.so _pytj.o  _pytj_wrap.o \`python-config --libs\` -lturbojpeg -Wl,-z,defs 2>&1 | head`

Comment: @slugonamission Does not work, see edit. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear and even suggest actions to remedy the problem: recompile libturbojpeg with -fPIC. Code in shared libraries must be position-independent since the base address of a loaded library isn't  known beforehand.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky But why is gcc ignoring the libraries in the original arguments order? And why can I link to turbojpeg if I am linking an executable instead of another shared library?

Comment: @giomasce the linker is not ignoring the libraries; the observed behavior is due to the symbol resolution algorithm. Basically if N-th item on the command line needs foo, only subsequent items are searched for foo. But in your case a library providing foo apears before the object requesting foo. Executables don't need to be position-independent, that's why its possible to link your variant of turbojpeg when building an executable.